# How to remove corner radius of the formsheet style UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

```
    @IBAction func popOverRadarChart(sender: UIButton) {

    let popOverViewController = ResultTwoPopoverViewController(nibName: "ResultTwoPopoverViewController", bundle: nil)

    popOverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FormSheet
    popOverViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
    popOverViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(540, 622)
    popOverViewController.view.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0
    popOverViewController.view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    presentViewController(popOverViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

**If I could remove those four corner radius to 0.0.**[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well in your `ResultTwoPopoverViewController` overide the `viewWillLayoutSubviews`

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
      [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
      self.view.superview.layer.cornerRadius  = 0.0;   
      self.view.superview.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It works for me with this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    //change the cornerRadius
    self.view.superview.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Also notice that if you are embedding the view controller into a navigation controller you have to do `navigationController?.view.superview?.layer.cornerRadius = 4`